# npm: Keep installed package when error occurs

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install a package (`iohook`) that fails during a build step.

The package itself encourages me to build it myself by entering into `node_modules/iohook` and running `npm run build`.

```
npm ERR! Try to build for your platform manually:
npm ERR! # cd node_modules/iohook
npm ERR! # npm run build
```

However, the folder gets automatically deleted when an error occurs during installation, so I can't perform the manual step.

How can I force `npm` to keep the package "installed" even when an error occurs?